# What is the path of the JVM inside the JRE?

Tags: java

I am just learning Java and I wanted to know that everywhere its written that  JVM present inside JRE. I just wanted to know the complete path where exactly JVM is present inside JRE.

Comment: You should ideally try to elaborate on your intentions in order to get the best possible answer. What exactly are you looking for? The VM executable? The libraries that together constitute the VM? What do you need this for, just out of curiousity?

Answer (score 5):

In Windows : inside your JRE, you will have a folder like this : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client` --> this directory contains the client JVM `jvm.dll`.

Under :linux you will find it in `/jreInstallation/lib/yourSystemArchtecture(amd64 in my case)/(server/client)/libjvm.so`

A VM is nothing but a shared library like `dll` or `so` file. Your java exe or other executable file calls the jvm.

Note : You can call your JVM using any language / executable file/ You could write a *shell script* or a cobol program to execute the JVM

Comment: @JHH - Well, yeah.. In case of other OS / platforms the directory structure will not vary much. Edited my answer though, to make it explicit :)

Comment: Sorry for being vague, my point was mainly that DLL files as such is a pure Windows concept. You could also argue that the actual java executable (be it /usr/bin/java, c:\program files\java.exe or whatever) is what constitutes the VM I guess?
To give a better answer I think we need to know the intention of the OP.

Comment: @JHH - I gave an answer for Linux as well.. both formats - so (for linux) and dll (for windows). These shared libaries are invoked by the `java` cmd.

Comment: My Oracle Java 8 contains `${JRE_HOME}/bin/server/jvm.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10, mine:
    C:\Users\elb>where java

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\java.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use the [Invocation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html) in a native application and access Java APIs installed as part of OpenJDK (Java 10, Java 11, etc.) in `${JAVA_HOME}` directory, link against (or dynamically load) `jvm.dll` found in `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/server/jvm.dll`.

Oracle installers (currently up to Java 8) add a Windows Registry key pointing to `jvm.dll`. For example, when JRE 8 is installed, the following key is added:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.8`

and it contains a string value `RuntimeLib` set to absolute path to `jvm.dll`. Also, information that `1.8` is the `CurrentVersion` can be found in key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`

As of Java 9, Oracle [abbreviated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-EEED398E-AE37-4D12-AB10-49F82F720027) `Java Runtime Environment` to `JRE`, so the keys are:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JRE
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JRE\9`

This is all documented [Windows Registry Settings section of the installation guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-microsoft-windows-platforms.htm#JSJIG-GUID-47C269A3-5220-412F-9E31-4B8C37A82BFB).